# Использование NLP для разрешения омографов

Tags: python, nlp

Есть размеченный корпус из 700 записей вида

```
амбарный замо`к
без труда открыл замо`к двери
бесшумно открыл замо`к
блестящий никелированный замо`к 
ближайший за`мок обнаружился
```

из которых 80% используется для обучения, остальное для теста.

Используется библиотека gensim. Модель создается так:

```
model = FT_gensim(size=28, window=5, workers=4, iter=5)  # FastText
model.build_vocab(sentences=dataset)
model.train(
    sentences=dataset, epochs=model.epochs,
    total_examples=model.corpus_count, total_words=model.corpus_total_words,
)
```

Где dataset это список списков слов. (Список строк корпуса, где каждая строка разделена на слова)

На запрос `model.wv.most_similar(positive=["щелкнул"])` модель дает такое предсказание:

```
[('вы', 0.36629483103752136),
 ('весь', 0.2819870412349701),
 ('щёлкнул', 0.230695903301239),
 ('за`мок', 0.2190021276473999),
 ('еще', 0.20068413019180298),
 ('на', 0.1991848647594452),
 ('большой', 0.16020019352436066),
 ('легко', 0.1342184841632843),
 ('дверной', 0.12372174859046936),
 ('висячий', 0.0880974680185318)]
```

В котором есть ошибочное ударение, но правильного нет вообще. Несмотря на то, что в корпусе 25 записей со словом "щелкнул" и его производными, которые определяют `замОк` и ни одной для `зАмок`

```
вверху щелкнул замо`к
вскоре замо`к щелкнул
замо`к входной двери щелкнул
```

Как модель для слова "щелкнул" предложила "за`мок" если нет ни одного предложения, в котором встречаются оба эти слова?
В чем ошибка? И как сделать правильно?

Comment: Что-то скор даже у верхних похожих слов какой-то смешной. И "вы" непонятно при чём. Посмотрите словарь - там вообще есть "замо`к", он там не разделился на части случайно? И ещё не очень уверен что у вас правильно FT проходится по корпусу. Может он не по предложениям работает, а по всему корпусу как по одной слитной строке и из-за этого подхватывает где-то ложные аналогии, тем более что окно у вас 5 (это много, мне кажется)? И не забывайте, что FT ещё и по биграммам учится, а не только по целым словам, тут тоже может быть засада.

Comment: Да, и ещё. Вы вообще понимаете, что такое эмбеддинги и что вам говорит `most_similar`? Он говорит вам, какие слова часто встречались *в таком же контектсе*. Ну, если я ничего не путаю. Это не совсем то, что вы проверяете, мне кажется.

Comment: @CrazyElf Чтобы быть уверенным что проходит по предложениям, специально передаю список списков, а не ссылку на корпус. Ударение не разделяет слово. Разделение происходит простым str.split() и косвенно подтверждается наличием слова с ударением в ответе. На счет понимания, оно поверхностное. Что не мешает считать, что контекст слова `щелкнул` должен быть `замОк`.

Comment: Да, и что вам кстати говорит `most_similar` по слову "замо`к"?

Comment: @CrazyElf [('щёлкнул', 0.19735334813594818),
 ('большой', 0.19322066009044647),
 ('дверь', 0.16922278702259064),
 ('открылся', 0.1619725525379181),
 ('дверной', 0.11949746310710907),
 ('закрыли', 0.11633917689323425),
 ('двери', 0.10611100494861603),
 ('зажигания', 0.10179127007722855),
 ('его', 0.09435302764177322),
 ('кодовый', 0.0721069723367691)]

Comment: Ага. Ну вы видите, какой маленький вообще скор? Это же смешно. У вас просто очень маленький корпус для FastText и прочих эмбеддингов, он просто ничему толком не научился по предложенным вами фразам.

Comment: Кстати, странно, что вы не удаляете стоп-слова - ну там предлоги и т.д. Они только замусоривают текст

Comment: Как вариант - слово "замо`к" встречается и в предложениях без слова "щелкнул", поэтому ещё так.

Comment: @CrazyElf Для двух состояний, для оценочного тестирования, количества должно хватить в первом приближении. И специально обратил внимание 25/0 записей правильно/неправильно, никак не должно выдвинуть на первый план неправильный выбор. Удаление слов из 3 и менее символов, только повысило коэффициент неправильного ударения, правильный ответ так и не предложив. Кроме увеличения размера корпуса, других советов нет?

Comment: @CrazyElf И основной вопрос сохраняется. Как модель для слова "щелкнул" предложила "за`мок" если нет ни одного предложения, в котором встречаются оба эти слова?

Comment: Я вам повторяю - вы не понимаете, что такое эмбеддинги и как работает word2vec. Вот есть два предложения: "Зима закончилась в начале февраля" и "Зима закончилась в начале марта". Если по ним построить эмбеддинги, то слово, наиболее "похожее" на "февраль" будет "март". И в обратную сторону точно так же - на "март" наиболее похож "февраль". При том, что слова "февраль" и "март" **не встретились в одном предложении**. Но они *наиболее похожи согласно построенной модели*, потому что *встречаются внутри корпуса в одинаковом контексте*. Так понятно?

Comment: ОК. В какую сторону смотреть для решения моей задачи? Классификации или-или по контексту?

Comment: Ну вообще ваш подход может и должен работать, я бы попробовал всё-таки посмотреть что скажет такой вариант, он тоже ошибётся или уже нет: `model.wv.most_similar(positive=[здесь перечислить все слова предложения, кроме слова, ударение в котором мы пытаемся определить])`. Но вообще правильный подход сразу не соображу, NLP я не очень много занимался

Comment: @CrazyElf Примерно так и поступаю. Тестом является часть корпуса, где в positive включаются все слова, кроме слова с ударением. good=52 / bad=58 / unknown=29. Unknown — когда в предсказании вообще нет целевого слова с ударением.

Comment: В общем, тут надо думать, читать всякое. Я просто вам указал, что вы немного не понимаете, что делаете, может тут вообще не word2vec надо использовать, я не уверен, надо думать.